# How to disable app window resizing on ipad when using stage manager?

Tags: swift, ipad, screen-size

I'm using Stage Manager support in my iPad app and I want the window size to be fixed or set to a minimum size.

I know how to do this for macOS, but I don’t find it for iPad

#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

```
    UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
    }
```

#endif

Answer (score 0):

Disable Portrait and Upside Down Orientation in Deployment Info can disable resizing the window in iPadOS Stage Manger.

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRfLY.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).